# How to open a JPG file as a BITMAP with the JPG stored on the SDCARD?

Tags: android, bitmap, jpeg

Actually i know how to open PNG files as bitmaps. But my code doens't works for open JPG files, i dont know why.

I can't find correct examples on SO or google about how to do this.

I need to have a bitmap with the JPG file opened from a dir of the sdcard. For example "sdcard/images/01.jpg"

Thanks

Comment: You have the use-permission to read from external storage, right?  That threw me for a bit.

Answer (score 55):

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
ImageView IV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id."image view");
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(root+"/images/01.jpg");
IV.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Always try to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` instead of sdcard.
You need an ImageView somewhere in your layout, however that's how I do this kind of things.

I use this code personally too, and it works here.

Comment: Which permissions do I need to set to run the code above?

Answer (score 11):

Any of the [`BitmapFactory.decode*`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29) methods should be able to handle standard JPG files.
If you post some code it could be easier to see why it won't work.